# Jquery Mobile Glitch using Panels and Page Transitions

Tags: jquery, mobile, panel, transition

I have implemented a Panel Navigation system using Jquery Mobile.  However, it seems that when a page transition occurs, there are some graphical glitches.  On my desktop chrome, the gradient on my pages looks squished during the transition.  When accessing the same page on my mobile chrome browser, a white line appears on the bottom of the pages during the transition.

Through my testing I have found that if I take out the panel navigation, than the graphical glitches go away as well.

Here is a sample of one of the pages. The other pages look the same structurally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Vidapp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></sc    ript>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/custom.css" />
</head>

<body> 
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

    <div data-id="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a href="#sidemenu" data-icon="bars">Menu</a>
    <h1>Contributions</h1>
    <a href="#" data-icon="home">Gift</a>
</div>

<div id="sidemenu" data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="/views/browse/trending.html">Trending</a></li>
        <li><a href="/views/browse/friends.html">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="/views/browse/contributions.html">Contributions</a></li>
        <li><a href="/views/browse/mygifts.html">My Gifts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" data-mini="true" placeholder="Have a Reference Code?" />
    <h2>My Contributions</h2>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is hosted here: [Demo of Error](http://vidapp.cardswap.ca/)

I cannot figure out what is causing these graphical glitches to occur!

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery Mobile website: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/panels/

> A panel must be a sibling to the header, content and footer elements inside a jQuery Mobile page. **You can add the panel markup either before or after these elements, but not in between.** A panel cannot be placed outside a page, but this constraint will be removed in a future version.

Try moving the panel to either before the header, or after the contact divs.

Comment: This problem still exist, even it is sibling of header and it is before header element in one of my app. But as I know those problems only appear on phone app, not on desktop browser.